# Disable option in select

Tags: jquery

I have this select:

```
<select>
    <option class="1">1st</option>
    <option class="2">other1</option>
    <option class="2">other2</option>
    <option class="1">2st</option>
    <option class="2">other1</option>
    <option class="2">other2</option>
</select>
```

How can I disable the options with class "1"?

Comment: Just a sidenote, your class names are invalid, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/1112384

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<select>
<option class="1">1st</option>
<option class="2">other1</option>
<option class="2">other2</option>
<option class="1">2st</option>
<option class="2">other1</option>
<option class="2">other2</option>
</select>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('select').find('option.1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

Note: Your class names are not following convention

Naming rules:

1. Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
2. Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"),
   and underscores ("_")
3. In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can do the following (whereas `c1` is a valid replacement for `1`)

```
jQuery("option.c1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

This fetches all elements of tag `option` that have a class of `c1` set and, for each matched tag, the attribute `disabled` is added with value `disabled` (this is common practice, as `disabled` does not really need an argument, but XML requires an argument for attributes).