# What is the 'AngularJS' way to disable an 'option' HTML5 element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

What is the 'AngularJS' way to disable an 'option' HTML5 element?

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.25.

Plunk Link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/fS1uKZ

```
<!-- CODE BEGIN -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-require="angular.js@2.0.0" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- CODE END -->
```

I'm making a 'form' element and there are several 'select' element tags with several 'option'  element tags.

The 'option' element tags have identical attributes throughout all four of the 'select' element tags.

I want the user to rank the car manufacturers. When they select a manufacturer, I want to disable that 'option' element in all four 'select' element tags.

I found the following question/answer, but is this the 'AngularJS' way? ([Disable option in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969798/disable-option-in-select))

They are using jQuery and I know that AngularJS contains 'jQuery Lite', but is that implementation the 'AngularJS' way?

I found this documentation at the AngularJS site:
htt9$://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

This is the accompanying Plunk link:
htt9$://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

I can appreciate the example provided by the AngularJS team. I was thinking about modifying ng-model and/or ng-disabled. I would like to avoid 'hacking' AngularJS 'core' files.

Do I decouple ng-model and/or ng-disabled?

Or, should I craft a custom filter?

I come from a jQuery background, and I'm trying to adhere to AngularJS best practices as much as possible. I want to prevent excessive 'technical debt'.

Comment: To me radio buttons would seem a better form component to use than selects. Would you consider trying it with radio buttons, or are the lists too long?

Comment: Do you have any specifics when you want to disable any condition ?

Comment: @jpumford Yeah, radio buttons would be better. The list isn't static and may increase.

Comment: @Susheel Yes I do have specific conditions for disabling the 'option' tag. I want to disable it when it is selected in any of the other drop-down(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular way to disable a select option is to use `ng-disabled="expression"`
[This plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SjSjrlBeddzdcHzfAMQI) shows how it's done.

In you case you can have 4 selects like so:

```
<select ng-model="model.selected1">
  <option ng-repeat="c in model.options" value="{{c.value}}" ng-disabled="model.should_disable(c, 1)">{{c.label}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="model.selected2">
  <option ng-repeat="c in model.options" value="{{c.value}}" ng-disabled="model.should_disable(c, 2)">{{c.label}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="model.selected3">
  <option ng-repeat="c in model.options" value="{{c.value}}" ng-disabled="model.should_disable(c, 3)">{{c.label}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="model.selected4">
  <option ng-repeat="c in model.options" value="{{c.value}}" ng-disabled="model.should_disable(c, 4)">{{c.label}}</option>
</select>
```

where model.options is your list of options

```
var model = $scope.model = {
    options: [
      {label: 'Volvo', value: 'volvo'},
      {label: 'Audi', value: 'audi'},
      {label: 'Saab', value: 'saab'},
      {label: 'Opel', value: 'opel'},
    ],
    should_disable: should_disable
}
```

That function should_disable(c, num) is supposed to be true when car c is selected in a `<select>` other than num.

```
  function should_disable(c, selectnum){
    var other_selectnums = [1,2,3,4].filter(function(n){
      return n != selectnum;
    });
    var is_selected_somewhere_else = false;
    for(var i=0; i<other_selectnums.length; i++){
      var otherselectnum = other_selectnums[i];
      if(c.value == model['selected'+otherselectnum]){
        is_selected_somewhere_else = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return is_selected_somewhere_else;
  }
```

[Here's a fully working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3VToHzpMvLcPJvQgezJR?p=preview)